# Почему не передаются значения

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать редактирование товара. Но при выводе формы она выводится незаполненной. (форма как всплывающее окно выполнена)

`view:`

```py
def parts(request):
    added = ''
    error = ''
    PartAllView = Part.objects.order_by('-id')

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'parts_add' in request.POST:
        form = PartForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            added = 'Добавлено'
        else:
            error = 'Данная запчасть уже добавлена'

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'parts_edit' in request.POST:
        PartPost = int(request.POST['parts_edit'])
        PartID = Part.objects.get(id=PartPost)
        if PartID:
            PartID.save()
            added = 'Запчасть успешно отредактирована'
        else:
            error = 'Ошибка редактирования'

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'parts_delete' in request.POST:
        PartPost = int(request.POST['parts_delete'])
        PartID = Part.objects.get(id=PartPost)
        if PartID:
            PartID.delete()
            added = 'Запчасть успешно удалена'

    form = PartForm()

    data = {
        'added': added,
        'error': error,
        'form': form,
        'PartAllView': PartAllView,
    }

    return render(request, 'kross/parts.html', data)
```

`HTML:`

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal fade" id="partEdit{{ el.id }}">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered text-center" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h6 class="modal-title">Добавление запчасти</h6><button aria-label="Close" class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Форма для заполнения -->


    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row row-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.brand }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.number }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.name }}<br>
            {{ form.description }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{ form.analog }}
      <br>
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-0" style="float: left;">Главное фото</label>
        {{ form.images }}<br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-0" style="float: left;">Дополнительные фото</label>
        {{ form.images0 }}<br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-0" style="float: left;"></label>
        {{ form.images1 }}<br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-0" style="float: left;"></label>
        {{ form.images2 }}<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" name="parts_add" class="btn btn-primary">Отредактировать</button>
      <button class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему должно быть иначе? вы пустой объект и передаете form = PartForm()

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev а что тогда надо передать, или заводить новый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было поставить `input` и значения из цикла

```
 {% for el in PartAllView %}

<!-- Форма редактирование начало -->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal fade" id="partEdit{{ el.id }}">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered text-center" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h6 class="modal-title">Добавление запчасти</h6><button aria-label="Close" class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>

    <!-- Форма для заполнения -->


    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row row-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ el.brand }}">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ el.number }}">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ el.name }}"><br>
            <input type="textarea" class="form-control" value="{{ el.description }}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? если первое, то, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. а если второе, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите