# Как сделать, чтобы код python перезапускался самостоятельно, в случае отключения?

Tags: python

Как сделать чтобы код python перезапускался самостоятельно, если такое возможно? Может есть кусочек кода с перезапуском? Просто мой код находится на сервере pythonanywhere, а они там, мягко говоря, болаболы, пишут, что отключение кода произойдёт через овермного часов, а он уже в середине дня перестаёт работать, устала по 200 раз на дню перезагружать. И нет, это не из за ошибки в коде, он просто реально отключается.

Comment: Это зависит от того, как именно когд отключается. На каком уровне. С ошибкой какой-то падает скрипт, или ОС прямо процесс убивает?

Comment: Смотря что за скрипт. Если там он постоянно процессор грузит, то он быстро все выделенное время будет отъедать. Если добавить просто time.sleep, то уже меньше будет грузить процессор. А может вообще скрипт не принудительно завершается, а у вас какое-то исключение вылетает, нужно логирование ошибок добавить, и потом уже смотреть (нет, я по умолчанию не верю, что у вас нет ошибок в коде).

Comment: Да он у меня просто через некоторое время отключается, read time out что то там

Comment: @Alexander То есть сам скрипт? Ну сделайте там вечный цикл и оберните вызов вашего кода в `try-except`. Покажете ваш код где вызовы самого верхнего уровня - можно будет конкретно показать

Answer (score -1):

Если я вас правильно понял то вот

```
import atexit
import time
 
import winreg as reg  
import os              
 
def DeleteFromRegistry(value): 
    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    hive = reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
    subKey = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
      
    # open the key to make changes to 
    hKey = reg.OpenKey(hive, subKey, 0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 
 
    reg.DeleteValue(hKey, value)
    
    # now close the opened key 
    reg.CloseKey(hKey) 
 
def AddToRegistry(value): 
  
    # in python __file__ is the instant of 
    # file path where it was executed  
    # so if it was executed from desktop, 
    # then __file__ will be  
    # c:\users\current_user\desktop 
    script = os.path.realpath(__file__) 
    # joins the file name to end of path address 
    address = f"python.exe {script}"  
      
    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    hive = reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
    subKey = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
      
    # open the key to make changes to 
    hKey = reg.OpenKey(hive, subKey ,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 
      
    # modifiy the opened key 
    reg.SetValueEx(hKey, value, 0,reg.REG_SZ,address) 
      
    # now close the opened key 
    reg.CloseKey(hKey) 
 
 
def goodbye(name, adjective):
    DeleteFromRegistry("MyScript")
    print('Goodbye, %s, it was %s to meet you.' % (name, adjective))
 
 
atexit.register(goodbye, "MyScript", 'nice')
AddToRegistry("MyScript")
 
#---------------------------------------
x = 0
 
# пока прога работает - 30 секунд - она в автозапуске; как только завершается (корректно) - ее там уже нет.
while x < 30:
    time.sleep(1)
    x+=1
```

Comment: На pythonanywere linux, ваше решение через реестр Windows там не заработает.

Comment: К тому же с отступами беда.

Comment: @insolor не очень удобно код вставлять поэтому отступы такие

Comment: @Капуста Вставляете код как есть, потом весь блок помечаете как код - и всё.

Comment: Вставьте код как есть и добавьте три косых апострофа ``` или три тильды ~~~ выше и ниже него. Посмотрите как в этом вопросе вам код оформили и сделайте тут по аналогии: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409326/1365